# Is my Nepalese MCA considered valid and equivalent to Indian MCA in India?

Tags: masters, india

I have a Master's in Computer Applications (MCA) from the Purbanchal University of Nepal.  I intend to apply for a MTech CSE in India as people with MCA are eligible to study MTech CSE in India.
Is the Nepalese MCA considered valid and equivalent to Indian MCA in India?

Comment: For what purpose? Admittance to a doctoral program in India? For employment?

Comment: @mkennedy
to study MTech CSE in India as people with MCA are eligible to study MTech CSE in India...